# Arrays multidimensionales PHP

Tags: php

Para un ejercicio académico tengo que crear un array de cinco dimensiones, para lograrlo he construido la siguiente estrutura: `

```
        $data = array(
            array ( array (0,1,2,3,4,5),
                    array (0,1,2,3,4,5),
                    array (0,1,2,3,4,5),
                    array (0,1,2,3,4,5),
                    array (0,1,2,3,4,5)
                )             
        );

    ?>`
```

Mi pregunta ¿Estoy realmente creando con esta estructura un array 5x5, al crear un array que contiene cinco arrays a su vez dentro de él y cada uno de estos con una loguitud de cinco?

Comment: Eso que plasmas es un `array` de 3 dimensiones en cuya tercera dimensión tienes 5 arrays con 6 valores.

Comment: Si quisiera entonces, crear un array de 5x5 ¿tendría que añadir dos dimensiones más y restar un valor?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que debés crear un array de 5 dimensiones y no uno de 2 dimensiones de 5x5?

Comment: Las especificaciones dicen literalmente " genera una matriz (array) 5 x 5 de números enteros aleatorios entre 0 y 9."  Primero estoy abordando la creación de la matriz.

Comment: Una matriz es un array de 2 dimensiones, y en este caso sus dos dimensiones son 5 y 5

Comment: Cuando se habla de un array 5x5 , al igual que en matemáticas cuando hablamos de un cuadrado de 5x5, lo que obtienes de él son 25 valores (5x5 = 25). Un cuadrado tiene 2 dimensiones por lo que necesitas un array bidimensional para conseguirlo. (el primer `array` es el alto del cuadrado, el que recorre las **filas** y el segundo `array` es el ancho del cuadrado, el que recorre las **columnas** de cada fila)

Comment: Perfecto, me ha quedado muy claro. A la hora de rellenarlo con valores aleatorios de 0 a 9, puedo hacerlo con la función rand, especificando un valor mínimo y máximo. ¿Cómo los implemento dentro de la propia matriz?

Comment: Eso ya sería otra pregunta que se aleja del enunciado de esta. Si haces una nueva y muestras como has intentado generar esos números aleatorios (para que se vea que te estás peleando con ello) estoy seguro de que alguien podrá ayudarte.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que la declaración debería ser de este modo

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
);
```

Posterior para iterar y poder apreciar la estructura de 5*5 hacer lo siguiente; es decir necesitas de un doble `foreach`

```
foreach($data as $numero){
    foreach($numero as $elemento){
        echo $elemento;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado leo que vas a llenarlo con números aleatorios, por lo que pudieras auxiliarte de la función `rand()` e indicar los números extremos para llenar así

```
rand(0, 9);
```

Answer (score 2):

Para crear un array de 2 dimensiones (matriz) de 5x5 debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
  $data = array(
    array (0,1,2,3,4),
    array (0,1,2,3,4),
    array (0,1,2,3,4),
    array (0,1,2,3,4),
    array (0,1,2,3,4)
  )
```

Te está sobrando el array que envuelve a los otros arrays.